# ¿Existe alguna forma para sugerir cambios en mensajes del sitio que pueden ser ofensivos?

Tags: discusión, soporte

El siguiente mensaje puede resultar un poco ofensivo, cuanto menos desagradable

> Gracias por enviar la edición. Será visible solo por ti hasta que haya
> sido aprobada por miembros confiables de la comunidad

« *... miembros confiables de la comunidad*» ¡¿Yo no soy confiable?! ¡¿Cualquiera con menos de x reputación no es confiable?!

Sería mucho mejor, «*miembros autorizados*», por ejemplo.

En fin, ¿dónde se pueden hacer este tipo de sugerencias?

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122932/discussion-on-question-by-eniel-rod-existe-alguna-forma-para-sugerir-cambios-en).

Comment: @Pikoh ¿por qué enviaste los comentarios a un chat? típicamente los comentarios en mera estan hechos para discutir temas a diferencia de lo lógica del sitio principal.

Comment: @eyllanesc el sistema levanta un flag automaticamente tanto en el sitio principal como en meta cuando una publicación tiene mas de 20 comentarios. Que en meta historicamente se haya tenido algo mas de "manga ancha" no significa que en meta no aplique la normal general de que los comentarios son susceptibles de ser movidos a un chat o incluso eliminados. De todas maneras,siguen siendo accesibles de igual forma,solo que en una sala de chat

Comment: @Pikoh Entiendo tu punto pero de mi experiencia en meta de SOen y Meta de Stack Exchange(no necesariamente se aplica al meta de SOes) siempre ha habido la practica de dejar esos comentarios abiertos porque asi todo la comunidad puede seguir discutiendo. A diferencia del sitio principal donde se espera que no haya discusiones en los meta se promueve ello para entender los puntos de vistas de todos. Nota: al final es tu decisión, con este comentario solo quiero recalcar porque pienso que no deberian mandarse al chat los comentarios de meta.

Comment: @eyllanesc tu opinión es igual de respetable que la mia, y entiendo perfectamente tu punto de vista,solo quería aclarar que en principio las normas aplican igual aqui que en el sitio principal. Podría perfectamente haber rechazado el flag,pero entendí que la posible discusión puede continuar de igual forma (mejor de hecho,mas extendida y dinamica sin ocultar la publicación principal) en el chat,y puede seguir participando toda la comunidad de igual forma. Por supuesto estoy a favor de conversar para que todos podamos explicar nuestro punto de vista! Y gracias por darme el tuyo :)

Answer (score 11):

Voy a tratar de responder a los temas que planteas:

En cuanto a tu pregunta *¿Existe alguna forma para sugerir cambios en mensajes del sitio que pueden ser ofensivos?* la respuesta es: aquí, en Meta, donde correctamente lo has hecho.

Ahora hablemos de el mensaje que consideras ofensivo, y aquí ya entramos en opiniones personales.

El mensaje al que haces alusión, como alguien explicó en los comentarios, es una traducción directa del mensaje del sitio en ingles, donde se habla de "trusted users" (usuarios confiables).

En mi opinión esto es perfectamente correcto, y no debe ser ofensivo para nadie. La confianza en todos los ámbitos de la vida debe ganarse, lo cual no significa que alguien que no se haya ganado dicha confianza sea per se indigno de la misma. Simplemente, debe demostrar que lo es.

Creo que todos sabemos que, en sitios con tantos usuarios como puede ser este, siempre existe un porcentaje de usuarios cuya intención no es aportar al sitio, sino todo lo contrario. En un ambiente de anonimato relativo, la única forma de discriminar unos de otros es mediante algún tipo de análisis de comportamiento durante el tiempo. En los sitios de la red StackExchange, esto es basado en la reputación. Por tanto, si, en los sitios de la red la confianza debe ganarse a base de reputación. Esto creo que no debe ser ofensivo para nadie, pero obviamente cada persona tiene su sensibilidad en un punto diferente.

Por último, he visto también en los comentario que te quejabas de los votos negativos a tu pregunta.

Meta es el sitio donde hacer sugerencias y discutir sobre el funcionamiento del sitio. El funcionamiento se intenta que sea lo mas democrático posible, y de momento la herramienta que tenemos para decidir se basa en los votos. Es posible que no sea perfecta, pero es lo que tenemos.

Por tanto, te recomiendo que no te ofendan los votos negativos, en meta los votos implican acuerdo o desacuerdo con la sugerencia planteada en la publicación.

En este caso, algunos usuarios del sitio consideran que sugieres modificar "usuario confiable" por "miembros autorizados", y expresan que no están de acuerdo con dicho cambio mediante su voto negativo. Este voto no es a tu persona, ni a que hagas la sugerencia (para eso esta meta precisamente, y todo el mundo puede hacer las sugerencias sobre el sitio que desees), sino directamente al cambio que planteas. Si una mayoría de gente hubiera votado a favor, se trataría de implementar el cambio sugerido, pero en este caso la mayoría no quiere que ese cambio se produzca.

Perdón por la extensión de mi respuesta, pero espero que gracias a ella entiendas un poco mas el funcionamiento de este sitio. Me gustaría aclarar para finalizar que este modo de funcionamiento no es exclusivo de StackOverflow en Español, sino de [todos los sitios de la red](https://stackexchange.com/sites).